# nginx dynamic proxy_pass with variable location

Tags: nginx, dynamic, config, request-uri

i want to setup a dynamic proxy pass. 
If i enter for example https://sub.mydomain.com/33544 then i want that the proxy pass to 
https://10.10.10.10/33544. 
So the only thing that change is the $request_uri.

So how must i config the location block that it will be redirect with the correct $request_uri in my example 33544 to https://10.10.10.10/33544 or if i type in 34778 then i will redirect to https://10.10.10.10/34778.

https://sub.mydomain.com/33544 -> https://10.10.10.10/33544

https://sub.mydomain.com/34778 -> https://10.10.10.10/34778

```
server {
# Setup HTTPS certificates
 listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name  sub.mydomain.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

location / {

    proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10:8001/$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

Comment: Does the service on port 8001 require `https`? Use: `proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10:8001;` to pass the request upstream without changing it.

Comment: No it is just an example it can also be http://10.10.10.10:8001

Comment: @Richard Smith thanks for you answer. i didn't know that it is as simple like this :)